# Using of IDisposable

Tags: c#, memory-management, dispose

I have a `List<Pupil>` and every time the Pupil object raise an event Finish. That pupil will be removed from `List<Pupil>`. Pupil object implemented an `IDisposable` interface.

Finish event.

```
    private void pupil_Finish(Pupilsender)
    {
        lock (this.pupilList)
        {
            if (this.pupilList.Contains(sender))
            {
                this.pupilList.Remove(sender);

                sender.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
```

So, after calling the method `this.pupilList.Remove(sender)`, should I use `sender.Dispose`? Purpose of those actions that I want to save the memory of my application.

Thanks!

Comment: Why is it implementing `IDisposable` in the first place? Do you have unmanaged memory to release?

Answer (score 1):

Disposables are not actually there for saving memory, but for explicitly releasing unmanaged resources. Objects' heap memory is freed by GC only. Therefore calling `Dispose` does not delete the object on the heap.

Answer (score 0):

If the sender pupil is not referenced anywhere else, then you should call Dispose. Otherwise not.

Comment: So does the method pupilList.Remove() dispose the pupil object?

Comment: No. pupilList.Remove() has nothing to do with pupil.Dispose(). If your pupil object has no use after it fires a "Finish" event, you should call Dispose right after the event invocation, but not during the event processing.

Answer (score 0):

The normal pattern would be for the `Pupil` to use its `Dispose` procedure to unsubscribe from any events it had subscribed to, and possibly raise a `Disposed` event which would notify other objects that they should take care of any `IDisposable` objects which they had lent the `Pupil` for its own use.  If `Finish` is supposed to behave as a `Disposed` event, there's no need to call `sender.Dispose`, since the whole reason the event is being raised in the first place is that `sender` is already being disposed.  That having been said, the `Finish` event handler should probably cancel its subscription, which it presently does not.